# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Изготовление затворов дисковых поворотных на основе новой концепции конструктивного исполнения по своим технико-эксплуатационным показателям позволит создать реальную конкуренцию затворам дисковым поворотным с самыми высокими достижениями производства ведущих мировых компаний.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы, наверно, всю фразу переделал.
 1. Технически правильнее: "Затвор поворотный дисковый" ("дисковый" - разновидность "поворотного").
 2. "..концепции конструктивного исполнения.." - речевая избыточность.
 3. "Изготовление" не обладает "технико-эксплуатационными показателями"
 4. "..затворам ... с ... достижениями.." - как-то не по-русски. Возможно, "..с ... характеристиками.."

"Изготовление затворов поворотных дисковых на основе новой концепции, благодаря их технико-эксплуатационным показателям, позволит создать реальную конкуренцию затворам поворотным дисковым с самыми высокими характеристиками производства ведущих мировых компаний."

Comment: @greydog, великолепно!

Answer (score 0):

Не нужны...
Но кто конкурирует? Затворы дисковые поворотные конкурируют с самыми высокими достижениями?
И потом — ведущие мировые компании производят самые высокие достижения? Что-то я не пойму...

Comment: Охо-хо... Ну, если вдуматься... Хотя то, что хотели сказать, понятно. Изготовление затворов позволит создать реальную конкуренцию... А что затворы производства ведущих мировых компаний, а не достижения - это, кажется, и так понятно...

Answer (score 0):

Есть у Розенталя правило, что определения, стоящие после определяемого слова, являются однородными. Правда, у него есть оговорка, что это правило не распространяется на случаи, когда определения входят в состав термина (пример из Розенталя: трубы тонкостенные электросварные нержавеющие)